# Removing absolute value from differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When using the method of separating variables when solving differential equations you often end up with an absolute value around y. For example:

$\frac {dy}{dt} = ky $

$\frac {dy}{y} = k dt$

After integrating both sides you get:

$ ln(|y|) = kt + C$

$|y| = Ce^{kt}$

Now I want to remove the absolute value around Y, how do I do that without breaking any mathematical rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** My previous answer was wrong. $C$ mustn't always be positive. Though the differential equation derivation leads to a positive RHS, it's *because* of the absolute value bars that the RHS is positive.

The absolute value here can abstract away negative solutions. That means, you'll have to split it into two possibilities:

$$y = Ce^{kt}$$
$$y = -Ce^{kt}$$

Thus, to remove the absolute value bars, rewrite as so:

$$y = \pm Ce^{kt}$$

Comment: It's ok, just edit your answer at the end. No need for points desperately :-) cheers

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik Done, thanks for you comments!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the expression of the right has the same sign of $C$, which is constant

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what i've read but I don't really understand it. Can I just lose the absolute value around Y with the motivation that the other side depends on C?

Comment: @AndrewLi yeah, I get that too, but that doesn't really explain why I can drop the absolute value for me. If C is negative, would't we want the absolute value then?

Comment: Be wary of posting "answers" that are significantly shorter than the Question to which they respond.  I don't see such an immediate application of the hint that additional explanation can or should be omitted.  Spell out your idea and show that it leads to a solution.

Comment: Well, $C=y(0)$ so it depends on how it is defined... Note that the other answer claims that $C$ is always positive, which is not true! For instance $y=-e^{kt}$ is a perfectly ok solution to your equation. Beware of accepting answers just because they are long. My hint was ok, I don't see why the downvote.